# Calling REST service method from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, rest

I am calling a REST service method from AJAX.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var xmml = getXmlLoginRequest();
        var wsdlURL = getWSDL('search');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: wsdlURL,   
            data: xmml, 
            contentType: "text/xml;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (result) {
                debugger;
                alert(" success" + result);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                debugger;
                alert(" error" + "jq :" + jqXHR + "textStatus :" + textStatus + "error : " + errorThrown);
            }
        });

        function getXmlLoginRequest() {
            debugger;
            var xml = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
             <soap:Body> \
                <search> \
                <qry>svein </qry> \
                </search> \
             </soap:Body> \
           </soap:Envelope>';

            return xml;
        }
        function getWSDL(methodName) {
            debugger;
            var url = 'http:/MyURL/search.php?username=abc&password=def';
            return url;
        }

    });
```

I am getting result as empty in success block. If I change dataType to `text`, I get an exception in Failure block which says `cannot parse NULL`.
Am I writing incorrect syntax? When I run the url on browser with method and its parameters, it gives proper result.

Comment: Don't seems problem with your code have u checked data in your url? is it returning ?

Comment: Yes it is returning data in xml form.

Comment: Not sure but if you can run on browser then it must be GET ? or do you use some tool to call the service from browser ?

Comment: I already changed it from POST to GET just for checking this. Still not worked.

Comment: I don't get the part how do you test the service from browser ?

Comment: Is it possible that you have NULL key or value if you're retuning JSON? You're missing a slash in your MyURL - could this be a problem? Are you sure you're not cross-domain scripting - your wsdlURL must match your page url.

Comment: My first guess would be that `getXmlLoginRequest()` isn't returning the `xmml` variable in time for it to be passed as a parameter in the AJAX request, and therefore the data you want isn't being returned.

Comment: @Andy Then it would have been the same case for wsdlURL. I don't think that's the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see here is SOAP and not REST. You should try [jQuery SOAP Plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/soap/) and not jQuery AJAX method directly.

Moreover WSDL Url is not the service URL, but URL of service description. The service URL is located in WSDL.

Service should be located on the same domain as your html page, because of same-origin-policy.

Answer (score 0):

The `dataTytpe` can be `xml, json, script, or html` only. Leave it blank for default: `Intelligent Guess`.

Also make sure that the URL `wsdlURL` will not violate the  [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).